# How do I enforce that a class passed in as a parameter can be parsed from a String in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I'm trying to represent a function call so that I can make a little scripting language for creating games. Right now I'm just trying to set up the interfaces between all the protocols and classes that I need. I have a class, `FunctionCall<T>`. It has a method `execute()` that executes the current function and returns an instance of type `T?`. `FunctionCall` also has a an array of instances of type `FunctionCall` to represent any parameters. It also has a field, `stringRepresentation`, which is a string representation of the function call, which the user will enter. This string might be something like `createNode(named: myCircle)` or, in the base case, it might be just a literal, like `myCircle`. To be clear, `myCircle` in this case is a `String`. I'm probably going to choose not to use quotation marks around `String`s in my little scripting language.

My problem is with the `execute()` method. I want to return an instance of type `T`. So far, I've thought of enforcing that `T` conforms to a protocol (let's call it `Parseable`) that enforces that it has a method that takes a `String` and returns an instance of type `T`. The problem I found with that approach is that I have no way of creating such a method, because I don't have a way to reference the type that will be implementing the protocol from within the protocol. In other words, if T is `SKShapeNode`, I have no way or referencing `SKShapeNode` from within `Parseable`, so that I can indicate that the return type must be an `SKShapeNode`. The other approach I found is to make `Parseable` have a required initializer that takes a `String`. This works when structs implement the protocol, but not with classes. The problem I get when I try to implement the protocol in a class is that the class wants me to make the initializer `required`, but I can't do that because I can't put a `required` initializer in an extension.

I want the `FunctionCall` class to look something like this

```
class FunctionCall<T: Parseable> {
    var parameters = [FunctionCall]()

    var stringRepresentation: String!

    init(stringRepresentation: String) {
        self.stringRepresentation = stringRepresentation
    }

    func execute() -> T? {
        guard let indexOfFirstLeftParen = stringRepresentation.firstIndex(of: "("),
            let indexOfLastRightParen = stringRepresentation.lastIndex(of: ")") else {
                // then this is a literal value, because no function is being called
                return T(string: stringRepresentation)
        }

        // TODO: implement

        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but how does `var parameters = [FunctionCall]()` compile? Do you have another `FunctionCall` that is non-generic?

Comment: I do not have another `FunctionCall` that is non-generic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem I found with that approach is that I have no way of creating such a method, because I don't have a way to reference the type that will be implementing the protocol from within the protocol.

Actually, that problem can be solved by using `Self`, which refers to whatever the conforming type is:

```
// I think this is a better name
protocol ConvertibleFromString {
    static func from(string: String) -> Self?
}

// implementation
extension Int : ConvertibleFromString {
    static func from(string: String) -> Int? {
        return Int(string)
    }
}
```

For non-final classes, you have to create a final subclass like this:

```
final class SKSpriteNodeFinal : SKSpriteNode, ConvertibleFromString {
    static func from(string: String) -> SKSpriteNodeFinal? {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that this prevents your protocol from being used as a variable's type:

```
var foo: ConvertibleFromString? = nil // error
```

But I don't think that will be a problem, as you only use `ConvertibleFromString` as generic constraints, which is OK.

Comment: Your code does not work for `SKShapeNode`. I think it's because `Int` is a struct whereas `SKShapeNode` is a class.

Comment: @R.Rincón It's not because `SKShapeNode` is a class. It's because `SKShapeNode` is not final. I guess you can work around this by making a final subclass of `SKShapeNode`, but I assume that's undesirable for you?

Comment: I see. I don't know. I might be okay with that, since I am, in addition to making the class final, actually extending the capability of the class. Please update your answer so I can mark it as the correct one.

Comment: @R.Rincón Edited. In that case, you can use your initialiser approach with a final subclass as well.